# Is there a way to completely ignore every question but the questions in your favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Is there a way to completely ignore every question but the questions in your favorite tags?

I already tried to put a `*` in ignored tags, but this just removes all questions.

I understand from the answers that this is not possible, hence I want to change this to a feature-request that this is actually possible in a similiar way to just normal ignored tags. In other words, I want to introduce a character in ignored tags, that causes to hide (or grey out) all non-favorite questions.

This is mainly relevant to Stack Overflow. Due to the extremely large traffic of over 5 questions per minute, it is not possible to read all of them. So I just want to read questions that are potientially interesting to me. It is unlikely I can answer a question about a language I don't use, and even if I could, it would probably be better if I helped someone else. So I just want to throw out the noise.

Comment: You may as well turn this into a feature request...

Comment: Since you want this to be a feature request, it would help if you provided justification for why this feature is important: What is wrong with things as it currently stands? How would this feature make Stack Exchange so much better?  Why is it important to be able to ignore every question but the ones in your favorite tags?  How does this make Stack Exchange more awesome?

Answer (score 12):

You're complicating the problem.

*ignore every question but the questions in your favorite tags* == *search for the questions in my favorite tags*

There're two variants:

1. Per-site: search for `intags:mine`.
2. To get the questions within the favorite tags all over Stack Exchange network: go to https://stackexchange.com/filters and select "Favorite Tags" filter.

Comment: One issue with this is, instead of a clean list of sortable questions like the home page, you get a jumble of questions and answers. You can fix this by searching for `intags:mine is:question`, which gives something more like the home page list

Answer (score 7):

> I already tried to put a * in ignored tags, but this just removes all questions.

I, and many others, think this should work, unfortunately ignored tags are prioritized above favorite tags. There is no way currently to accomplish what you're trying to do without your own client side script.

That said, there are a number of client side scripts others have created to handle ignored and favorited tags in a better manner.  [Search `ignored-tags script` and you should find a few.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=ignored-tags%20script)

Answer (score 4):

+1 for the feature request, it'd be great if there was a "my tags" link.

Fitting it into the UI could be a simple as turning "Favorite Tags" into a link.

---

There's a sort-of fiddly, awkward workaround in the meantime: bookmark a url that looks like this (note the pluses around the "or"s):

*(edit: [Nicael's magic alternative is easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269576/178621); disregard this below unless you wanted a subset of tags)*

> yoursite.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-tag-you-like+or+another-tag+or+some-third-tag

Or you can put the tags in the site's search box like this, which should take you to the same page:

> [some-tag-you-like] or [another-tag] or [some-third-tag]

Then sort by "active" and it'll remember your preference if you want new answers and edits instead of just new questions.

---

For example, I'm not normally interested in sci-fi or fantasy, but I am a fan of the Game of Thrones TV show and the books it's based on. With this URL, I can see only questions on those topics on the scifi SE site:

> https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire+or+game-of-thrones

Comment: @nicael - your edit is a different (probably better) answer, why not post it as an answer? Right now my answer reads like I'm having a bizarre conversation with myself

Comment: Just edit out yours and leave mine, if you wish :)

Comment: @nicael Well, no, because my original answer might be useful so people know it's possible to see a subset of their tags without un-favouriting tags. Just write your answer!

Comment: Okay then, not sure how useful it would be when I post an easier approach... I've reverted my edit.